# Implement neural network but backpropagation weights should be calculated using randomized optimisation?

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I was using sklearn python library for supervised learning algorithms. Now I have to do unsupervised learning algorithms. In this, I have to implement a neural network with weights for backpropagation to be optimised by either of following randomized optimisation algos:

1) Genetic Algo

2) Randomised Hill Climbing

3) Annealing

4) MIMIC

I used MLPClassifier for supervised learning, not sure what to do here.
Scikit has no implementation provided for this problem.

Sample code for NN is below(uses internal least square method for weight calculation):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#classification

Comment: It seems there are some misconceptions. NN-training has not much to do with least-squares optimization! Your task is also way too broad / or unclear and it's questionable if you did understand the difference between supervised- and unsupervised learning (as i read it).

Comment: Edit done. Is it now understandable ?

Comment: Its like I have to write a new MLPClassifier.

Comment: No it's not. You just removed least-squares and did not explain your task in more detail. Btw: in ML a classifier is considered supervised-learning. That's where the problem starts.

Comment: https://github.com/pushkar/ABAGAIL/blob/master/src/opt/RandomizedHillClimbing.java --- This has the implementation in java  of my problem

Comment: That is just a link to some optimisation code. There seems to be some confusion in what exactly you want to do. If you need to do unsupervised learning, this can be done with lots of algorithms in scikit-learn. If you are **just** interested in ANN's then unsupervised learning can still be done with backpropagation, similarly to supervised learning.